# Fixed dhcp ipv6 lease with windows seven?

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, ipv6

Here is my setup:

- my isp provides me with a /64 ipv6 adress (a real one, not through an ipv4 tunnel or whatever) in addition to my ipv4
- my router provides the ip with dhcp over my home network. I have given in its configuration fixed ipv4 leases but while it handles ipv6 fine there is no way to set a fixed ipv6 lease
- on the network i have a linux box and a windows box. For both, ipv4 and ipv6 works fine over the web, they have their own ipv6 adress that can reach them directly ect ...
- my linux box always keep the the same ipv6 adress, which is what I want and allows me to set things up easily.
- my windows box with windows seven pro x64 gets its fixed local ipv4 fine, but its ipv6 adress changes everytime. There even seems to be two ipv6 in its status windows, "ipv6 adress" and "temporary ipv6 adress".

My question here is, how can I configure windows to act like linux and ask the same ipv6 everytime ? I thought about setting it up myself in the adapter settings as a fixed ip, but then if it somehow isn't available windows won't be able to request another one over dhcp - unless I misunderstood it.

Does anyone knows how I can achieve that ? (i tried the "netsh interface ipv6 set global randomizeidentifiers=disabled", that didn't help)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the following in an admin console:

```
netsh interface ipv6 set privacy state=disabled
```